# how to make a seprated part of a object

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Okay, so I have this [image: here is my object]

and I can cut it so when I 3d print it I can take off the head and have something in side of it like an Arduino Uno and other stuff

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the reason to return original version of question with spelling and wording errors? It doesn't become clear because of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Edit mode.

Select the vertices or faces of the part you want to separate and press 'P'.

This opens the 'Separate' menu, where you can choose 'Selection'.

That's all. Now you will have that part as a separate object.